How can I get a "Date range" field to display the correct time?
I have a "Date range" field in my paragraph type.  I'm displaying the time in the node template like so:
{% for item in node.field_agenda_dates %}

   {% if item.entity.field_date.value is not empty %}
       <div>
          {{ item.entity.field_date.value|date("l, n/j") }}:
          {{ item.entity.field_time.value|date("g:i", 'America/New_York') }}
            -
          {{ item.entity.field_time.end_value|date("g:i a", 'America/New_York') }}
       </div>
   {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

The site's default timezone is New York, and the default PHP timezone is New York.  And in the field's display settings, I have the Timezone override set to New York.  So why do I see 6:00 in the output when I set field_time to 2:00?
Note: Other solutions on stackexchange might not work for "Date range" fields.  For example: Date display differences in node templates

I see the time displays as desired if I set the timezone to Anchorage in the twig template.  But it seems like there should be some other way:  {{ item.entity.field_time.value|date("g:i", 'America/Anchorage') }}

The site's default timezone is New York, and the default PHP timezone is New York. And in the field's display settings, I have the Timezone override set to New York. So why do I see 6:00 in the output when I set field_time to 2:00?
Drupal always stores UTC as raw field values. Use the field properties date and for a date range start_date/end_date. From there you can get Unix timestamps to handle them in Twig
{{ node.field_date.start_date.gettimestamp|format_date('custom', 'g:i A') }}

or format the dates in PHP preprocess. See How to get formatted date string from a DateTimeItem object

The item is a paragraph, and there is no start_date property available for the field, but there is a value and end_value.  Unfortunately when I use format_date, the time still displays according to the wrong time zone.  In other words, this doesn't work: {{ item.entity.field_time.value|date('U')|format_date('custom', "g:i") }} -- The output is exactly the same as with {{ item.entity.field_time.value|date("g:i", 'America/New_York') }}

This is only an example, node or paragraph doesn't matter. The field type matters, for a date range field value -> start_date and end_value -> end_date. For a standard date field value -> date. But you can't use start_date/end_date like the value, it's not a string but an object where you apply a method like ->getTimestamp() or ->format(), The second method works only in PHP.

But you can render the date object in Twig. It produces a long date/time format + timezone. Great for debugging, but not for displaying. This format is hardcoded and can't be changed.

For your last example try whether {{ item.entity.field_time.end_date }} reports a correct date/time + timezone.

It turns out all of these are available in a core datetime_range field:  value, end_value, start_date, end_date.  @4uk4 was on the right track.  I posted the working solution in my answer.

Actually, the solution by 4uk4 works well with just a minor tweak for use with paragraphs, so I'll mark it the correct answer.

This works:
{{ item.entity.field_time.start_date|date('U')|format_date('custom', "g:i") }}
{{ item.entity.field_time.end_date|date('U')|format_date('custom', "g:i") }}
or
{{ item.entity.field_time.start_date.gettimestamp|format_date('custom', "g:i") }}
{{ item.entity.field_time.end_date.gettimestamp|format_date('custom', "g:i") }}
This is very similar to the answer given by @4uk4.

Better use .gettimestamp instead of date('U'). It's the same result but more future-proof. You can't be sure that the date object will always produce a string that date('U') can use as input.
